# Sort Location(Lattitude, Longitude) based on shortest route path bing maps REST API

Tags: javascript, php, bing, bing-maps

I would like to order a Location(Latitude & longitude), such that the driving distance is the shortest.  When I have three points it would not matter going form A to B to C back to A or  from A to C to B and back to A. Using Bing maps REST API.

Comment: Have You Tried Any Solution? If Yes, Please Paste Your Tried Code In Question Too.

Comment: I tried Routes API from bing to calculate distance, but it returns the travel distance from A to B, B to C.

Answer (score 0):

Bing Maps has a new distance matrix service in preview which you can use to calculate these distances. You can find info on it here: https://labs.cognitive.microsoft.com/en-us/project-abu-dhabi

Not sure what you mean by sort;

- If you simply want to sort by distance from A to a list of locations (B, C...) then once you have the distance information this would be a simple array sort call.
- If you want to calculate the shortest route between all points, then this would be a travelling sales men problem and require a lot more code. There are a lot of different algorithms for doing this online. I have a few samples using Bing Maps somewhere on my computer, will see if I can find some time to clean them up and get them online.

Comment: Thank you, i want to calculate the shortest route between all points. Is there any API (even it is licensed one)?

Comment: There is no travelling salesmen routing feature in Bing maps at this time.

Comment: Thank you. I found the solution for travelling salesmen routing feature in google map api  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#Waypoints